# Numpy error when creating GIF using images2gif.py

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm trying to create a GIF file using images2fig.py from the visvis package

With this very simple code

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
from visvis.vvmovie.images2gif import writeGif

images = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob("*.png")]
filename = "test.gif"
writeGif(filename, images, duration=0.2)
```

I got an error

```
    writeGif(filename, images, duration=0.2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 570, in writeGif
    images = gifWriter.convertImagesToPIL(images, dither, nq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 373, in convertImagesToPIL
    im = Image.fromarray(im,'RGB')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1937, in fromarray
    obj = obj.tobytes()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tobytes'
```

What did I do wrong? How do I fix this?

I'm using Python 2.7.5, PIL 2.0.0-1, numpy 1.7.1-2, all are standard installation from Python(x,y) 2.7.5, and visvis 1.8 which is the latest version.

Comment: Please give the versions of Python, PIL/Pillow, bumpy, and visvis.

Comment: @abarnert Updated the info in OP.

Comment: Great, thanks. That implies that my guess was right.

Comment: By the way, nice catch. It looks like the visvis guys ran into this bug, didn't figure it out, and just haven't tried running their code with Pillow since… Hopefully the 2.1.0 fix will spur them to get back to testing with Pillow, which AFAIK was the only thing stopping them from full Python-3.x compat…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like [Pillow bug#224](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/pull/224).

From what I can tell, the bug was introduced in 2.0.0 and fixed in 2.1.0 ([checked in 21 May 2013](https://github.com/jiffyclub/Pillow/commit/108217303077bdb6b85cf4563b2a3804a61f1d40)). So, you should be able to fix it just by upgrading Pillow.

(If you're using a very old version of numpy, or Python 3.x, or a pre-2.0 Pillow (or PIL), this is not your bug. But none of those apply to you.)

Comment: That fixed the problem. But I got another error. I'm updating the OP.

Comment: @LWZ: The new error looks completely different from, and probably unrelated to, the original one. Better to post a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: You're right, I posted a new one here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18325419/1382745

Comment: @LWZ: Unfortunately, I can't get visvis working on my system, so I can't help with the new problem. But hopefully someone else can.