# Error when creating GIF using images2gif.py

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm trying to create a GIF file using images2fig.py from the [visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/) package

With this very simple code:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
from visvis.vvmovie.images2gif import writeGif

images = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob("*.png")]
filename = "test.gif"
writeGif(filename, images, duration=0.2)
```

I got an error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 575, in writeGif
    gifWriter.writeGifToFile(fp, images, duration, loops, xy, dispose)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visvis\vvmovie\images2gif.py", line 436, in writeGifToFile
    fp.write(globalPalette)

TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list
```

How do I fix this?

I'm using Python 2.7.5, Pillow 2.1.0, numpy 1.7.1-2, all are standard installation from Python(x,y) 2.7.5 on Windows, and visvis 1.8 which is the latest version. I tried to reinstall the packages but it did not help. I still get the same error. A friend of mine reproduced the error on his computer too.

Comment: Using pip to install visvis and PIL, I ran your exact code on two png files and had no errors on linux. Is that the actual code you ran?

Comment: @korylprince Yes that's the code I'm running. I'm on Windows though. I updated PIL from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 but Python(x,y) is still showing 2.0.0, maybe that is the problem. But I don't know how to properly update the package, the "remove package" function doesn't work.

Comment: perhaps you should try running `help(writeGif)` to learn about the particular version of the function you are running.

Comment: @korylprince it says `PILLOW_VERSION = '2.1.0'
    VERSION = '1.1.7' `, seems like it's updated properly. How can I reinstall the packages using `pip` on Windows? Worth a try.

Comment: I'm not sure... You can just install `pip` on windows then run `pip install PIL visvis`. That might get it working.

Comment: @korylprince I reinstalled packages and it did not help. Also, the error was reproduced on another computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35870/discussion-between-korylprince-and-lwz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@korylprince I fixed the problem with the following two changes:

1. I uninstalled Python(x,y), installed Anaconda (32-bit), then
   installed visvis via pip.
2. Instead of PIL Image, now I use `imread(image)`, which load image
   into a numpy array.

On another computer I did not uninstall Python(x,y), instead I uninstalled `Pillow 2.1.0` and installed `PIL 1.1.7`, and also replaced the code same as step 2 above. In that way it worked with Python(x,y). So the problem is `Pillow 2.1.0`.